# How to match and change strings in a column of a semicolon and double inverted commas separated file?

Tags: awk

I would like to query on below data format file. File has two delimiters
`"value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6","value7"`
Based on `value2` i would like to print `value4` and `value5`.

can any one please provide me a command to get this out put as i am unaware about how to query on multiple delimiters. 
I know below query but not giving desired output

`gawk 'BEGIN {FS=","} $1=="value2"  {print $0}' 20150701map.csv`

Comment: what is the second delimiter?  Seems like a csv file input.  Please post a sample input and desired output.  To print fields 4 and 5 you should do this.  `awk -F, '{print $4 FS $5}'`.  If you want this conditionally on the value of $2, do this `awk -F, '$2=="\"value2\"" {print $4 FS $5}'.  As long as you don't have commas in the quoted values awk can handle it with ease, otherwise I suggest use another tool.

Comment: Thanks for your response...I got the desired output and command...

Comment: if this is a CSV file, you will eventually come across commas inside the values. That is where awk will fail and you need to search for another tool. A quick google search finds solutions for perl, python, javascript and more.